# Extracting message attachments from PST files Microsoft Outlook using python

Tags: python, email, parsing, outlook, pst

I have a PST file with messages. I need to extract all attachments in messages using Python and save them separately in another directory with the same names as they actually have. Please tell me how I can do this?

I want to add one important caveat: I am developing a program for Linux, and more specifically, I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook Object Model, call `Application.Session.AddStore`, retrieve the new Store object from the `Application.Session.Stores` collection (`AddStore` does not return the new `Store` object), call `Store.GetRootFolder` to get the top level `MAPIFolder` object, recursively process its `MAPIFolder.Folders` and `MAPIFolder.Items` collections to extract messages. For each `MailItem` object, process its attachments (`MailItem.Attachments` collection) and call `Attachment.SaveAsFile`.

Comment: Please tell me, which library is used here?

Comment: Outlook Object Model (assuming the desktop version of Outlook is installed). Start at the `Application` object and work your way down its child objects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application

Comment: But in this case, I will need to install Outlook. And I wanted something more autonomous, so that my program could be wrapped in docker and transferred from system to system.

Comment: I am not aware of any Python libraries that can parse standalone PST files.